# Retrieve only column with value larger than 0

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a display that only show the column with value larger than 0.

My code to display the field and value :

```
echo "<table><tr>";
while ($property = mysql_fetch_field($result))
{
    if($property->name > '0')
    echo "<td>Field name: " . $property->name . "</td>";
}
echo "<tr/>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['a']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['b']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['c']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['d']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The output is like this :

```
Field name: a   Field name: b   Field name: c   Field name: d
1               2               3               0
```

I want to have a display like below :

```
Field name: a   Field name: b   Field name: c   
1               2               3
```

Where the `field name: d` is not display because the value is 0.

How can I do that? Can I wish for some examples from you?

Thanks.

Comment: What if there's more than one record in the resultset, with 0 in different columns?

Comment: Best would be to restrict your query to filter only records that are > 0. Then your php side only process that recordset :)

Comment: The code is the part to display the value only, the query to select which row I wish to is not posted in here.

Comment: @NullPointer, how can I do it in query? Can I have some examples? Because I only manage to filter the value, and not the column (field).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
   echo "<tr>";
   if($row['a'] >0)    echo "<td>".$row['a']."</td>";  else echo"<td>-<td>";
   if($row['b'] >0)    echo "<td>".$row['b']."</td>";  else echo"<td>-<td>";
   if($row['c'] >0)    echo "<td>".$row['c']."</td>";  else echo"<td>-<td>";
   if($row['d'] >0)    echo "<td>".$row['d']."</td>";  else echo"<td>-<td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: This only filter the row part, but the column (field) is still there.

Comment: that would be same like this

Comment: I can do it manually, such as `if($row['a'] >0)    echo "<td>field name : a</td><td>".$row['a']."</td>";`, but is there any more effective way?

Comment: If b is 0 the value of c will be in the b column and the value of d will be in c column - not good

Comment: Is it possible to not display the entire column? Because I want to generate a PDF, something like a report. I want to save the space, and also look more cleaner. If not, the whole page will full of '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code modified as for proper expected result.

```
echo "<table><tr>";
while ($property = mysql_fetch_field($result))
{
    if($property->name > '0')
    echo "<td>Field name: " . $property->name . "</td>";
}
echo "<tr/>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    if($row['a'] > 0) echo "<td>".$row['a']."</td>";
    if($row['b'] > 0) echo "<td>".$row['b']."</td>";
    if($row['c'] > 0) echo "<td>".$row['c']."</td>";
    if($row['d'] > 0) echo "<td>".$row['d']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: may i ask  now what the difference between yours and mine answer ?

Comment: You can't do much change in this type of code. actually I didn't saw your code when I was building mine.

Comment: yes that is true, but as I had already created it so I posted it. I appropriate your work given +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
$disp_col_a = false;
$disp_col_b = false;
$disp_col_c = false;
$disp_col_d = false;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    if ($row['a'] > 0){
        $disp_col_a = true;
    }
    if ($row['b'] > 0){
        $disp_col_b = true;
    }
    if ($row['c'] > 0){
        $disp_col_b = true;
    }
    if ($row['b'] > 0){
        $disp_col_b = true;
    }
    $results[] = $row;
}

echo "<table><tr>";
if ($disp_col_a){
    echo "<td>Field name: a</td>";
}
if ($disp_col_b){
    echo "<td>Field name: b</td>";
}
if ($disp_col_c){
    echo "<td>Field name: c</td>";
}
if ($disp_col_d){
    echo "<td>Field name: d</td>";
}
echo "<tr/>";
foreach ($results as $results_row) {
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($disp_col_a){
        echo "<td>";
        if ($results_row['a'] > 0){
            echo $results_row['a'];
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    if ($disp_col_b){
        echo "<td>";
        if ($results_row['b'] > 0){
            echo $results_row['b'];
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    if ($disp_col_c){
        echo "<td>";
        if ($results_row['c'] > 0){
            echo $results_row['c'];
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    if ($disp_col_d){
        echo "<td>";
        if ($results_row['d'] > 0){
            echo $results_row['d'];
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Not to be picky, putting aside that at first glance it certainly makes more sense to let mysql do the heavy lifting here - why would you want to output some number of rows in an HTML table that have different numbers of columns? Aside from the permanent maintenance headache, this would, by some, be considered Bad Design from a visual aesthetics perspective. :)

At the same time, I do understand the concept of "Good Enough Is," so I won't complain too much.

Comment: My full code is a bit messy, and I'm just cut out the part that I faced the problem. The code posted here is not what actually in my code, it's just the concept. I'm doing this because I want to create a PDF generated from php, and I want to save the space by remove the unwanted fields. That's all.

Comment: Understood. In this case, then, I'll go with "Good Enough Is." :)